# Golang пакет YAML для хранения конфига

Tags: golang, yaml

Есть ли удобный пакет для хранения конфига в Golang, хотелось бы иметь лёгкую связь с файлом, и затем так-же легко обновлять отдельные поля конфига вызовом одной функции

Comment: https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

Comment: Я видел подобные, по сути это просто оболочки для работы с YAML. Хотелось бы что-то похожее на встроенную БД, ну конечно в идеале, так то можно и эту использовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Динамическая конфигурация, насколько мне известно, не является решённой задачей. «Вызвать функцию — и всё само встало» у вас на любом нетривиальном проекте без вашего кода не получится. Возьмём, например, соединение с базой. Чтобы изменить его динамически, вам нужно:

- Дождаться всех клиентов на нынешнем соединении.
- Заблокировать всем новые вызовы.
- Закрыть нынешнее соединение. (Ошибки!)
- Открыть новое соединение. (Ошибки!)

  - (Опционально.) Откатиться обратно, если есть ошибки.
- Разблокировать новые вызовы.

И всё это надо выполнять потокобезопасно.

И это только один параметр. Единственный вариант, когда полностью динамическая конфигурация проканает — это если вы с самого начала строили свою программу в функционально-реактивном стиле.

---

Отдельно хочется сказать, что  YAML имеет множество проблем, начиная с [норвежской ловушки](https://software-carpentry.org/blog/2015/06/why-we-cant-have-nice-things.html) и заканчивая [фокусами со временем](https://twitter.com/Foone/status/1094480745672765440). Многие рекомендуют JSON, TOML, или хранение конфигурации в окружении.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, приму к сведению на счёт YAML проблем, посмотрю в сторону TOML.